# Stream implementations

Tags: data-structures, scheme, racket

Can streams be implemented in DrRacket as they are in SICP?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes.

In fact, Racket has *several* things that might be useful to you in this regard; there are streams and stream constructors, generators, sequences, and a lazy language, along with the 'delay' and 'force' that (IIRC) SICP uses.

Just to get you started, here's the documentation page for Delayed Evaluation, which is probably closest to what you're asking about.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Delayed_Evaluation.html